# Does the no-cloning theorem mean that 2 systems can't have the same state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Does the no-cloning theorem say that 2 systems can't exists anywhere in the universe that have exactly the same state, or just that you can't achieve that by cloning but you can achieve it by some other means?

Comment: No-cloning means there is no deterministic (unitary) process which can clone an unknown quantum state.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310075/50583

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you, that answers my question. You can close it as duplicate, or should I just delete it?

Comment: Minuteearth has [a really good explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owPC60Ue0BE) of the No-Cloning Theorem.